# What is the cause of the "Java heap space" error related to the 'entityManagerFactory' bean?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

The Spring application is working fine on `2.6.4` but I need to use Spring `3.1.2` so I had to change all the deprecated syntax like `javax` to `jakarta` within my entity classes etc. However, this small change has caused the application to throw the follwoing exception like 20 minutes after runtime:

```
2023-09-14T10:34:20.197-04:00  INFO 8084 --- [  restartedMain] com.aegis.kyc.KycApplication             : Starting KycApplication using Java 20.0.2 with PID 8084 (C:\Users\Devopscrm\Documents\kyc\target\classes started by DevopsCRM in C:\Users\Devopscrm\Documents\kyc)
2023-09-14T10:34:20.198-04:00  INFO 8084 --- [  restartedMain] com.aegis.kyc.KycApplication             : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-09-14T10:34:20.234-04:00  INFO 8084 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2023-09-14T10:34:20.234-04:00  INFO 8084 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2023-09-14T10:34:20.765-04:00  INFO 8084 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-09-14T10:34:20.867-04:00  INFO 8084 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 97 ms. Found 35 JPA repository interfaces.
2023-09-14T10:34:21.312-04:00  INFO 8084 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8443 (https) 8080 (http)
2023-09-14T10:34:21.320-04:00  INFO 8084 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-09-14T10:34:21.321-04:00  INFO 8084 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.12]
2023-09-14T10:34:21.362-04:00  INFO 8084 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-09-14T10:34:21.364-04:00  INFO 8084 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1128 ms
2023-09-14T10:34:21.490-04:00  INFO 8084 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2023-09-14T10:34:21.528-04:00  INFO 8084 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.2.7.Final
2023-09-14T10:34:21.529-04:00  INFO 8084 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000406: Using bytecode reflection optimizer
2023-09-14T10:34:21.612-04:00  INFO 8084 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.boot.internal.EnversServiceImpl    : Envers integration enabled? : true
2023-09-14T10:34:21.626-04:00  INFO 8084 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.b.i.BytecodeProviderInitiator        : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : bytebuddy
2023-09-14T10:34:21.698-04:00  INFO 8084 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.o.j.p.SpringPersistenceUnitInfo      : No LoadTimeWeaver setup: ignoring JPA class transformer
2023-09-14T10:34:21.710-04:00  INFO 8084 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2023-09-14T10:34:21.923-04:00  INFO 8084 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection ConnectionID:1 ClientConnectionId: 13da464e-2c47-4c20-a774-aca6a0ab484f
2023-09-14T10:34:21.924-04:00  INFO 8084 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2023-09-14T10:34:22.270-04:00  INFO 8084 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.c.i.m.AuditMetadataGenerator       : Adding properties for entity: com.aegis.kyc.entity.AccountStatus
2023-09-14T10:34:22.271-04:00  INFO 8084 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.c.i.m.AuditMetadataGenerator       : Adding properties for entity: com.aegis.kyc.entity.Associated
2023-09-14T10:34:22.272-04:00  INFO 8084 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.c.i.m.AuditMetadataGenerator       : Adding properties for entity: com.aegis.kyc.entity.RevenueStream
2023-09-14T10:34:22.272-04:00  INFO 8084 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.c.i.m.AuditMetadataGenerator       : Adding properties for entity: com.aegis.kyc.entity.CompanyBIRCorporation
2023-09-14T10:34:22.273-04:00  INFO 8084 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.c.i.m.AuditMetadataGenerator       : Adding properties for entity: com.aegis.kyc.entity.BusinessType
2023-09-14T10:34:22.273-04:00  INFO 8084 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.c.i.m.AuditMetadataGenerator       : Adding properties for entity: com.aegis.kyc.entity.Affiliate
2023-09-14T10:34:22.274-04:00  INFO 8084 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.c.i.m.AuditMetadataGenerator       : Adding properties for entity: com.aegis.kyc.entity.Stationed
2023-09-14T10:34:22.274-04:00  INFO 8084 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.c.i.m.AuditMetadataGenerator       : Adding properties for entity: com.aegis.kyc.entity.ContactType
2023-09-14T10:34:22.274-04:00  INFO 8084 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.c.i.m.AuditMetadataGenerator       : Adding properties for entity: com.aegis.kyc.entity.SectionC
2023-09-14T10:34:22.275-04:00  INFO 8084 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.c.i.m.AuditMetadataGenerator       : Adding properties for entity: com.aegis.kyc.entity.Opportunity
2023-09-14T10:34:22.275-04:00  INFO 8084 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.c.i.m.AuditMetadataGenerator       : Adding properties for entity: com.aegis.kyc.entity.Assignment
2023-09-14T10:34:22.275-04:00  INFO 8084 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.c.i.m.AuditMetadataGenerator       : Adding properties for entity: com.aegis.kyc.entity.SectionA
2023-09-14T10:34:22.277-04:00  INFO 8084 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.c.i.m.AuditMetadataGenerator       : Adding properties for entity: com.aegis.kyc.entity.Code
2023-09-14T10:34:22.277-04:00  INFO 8084 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.c.i.m.AuditMetadataGenerator       : Adding properties for entity: com.aegis.kyc.entity.UserRole
2023-09-14T10:34:22.277-04:00  INFO 8084 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.c.i.m.AuditMetadataGenerator       : Adding properties for entity: com.aegis.kyc.entity.SectionB
2023-09-14T10:34:22.277-04:00  INFO 8084 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.c.i.m.AuditMetadataGenerator       : Adding properties for entity: com.aegis.kyc.entity.CodeType
2023-09-14T10:34:22.278-04:00  INFO 8084 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.c.i.m.AuditMetadataGenerator       : Adding properties for entity: com.aegis.kyc.entity.PowersOfAttorney
2023-09-14T10:34:22.278-04:00  INFO 8084 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.c.i.m.AuditMetadataGenerator       : Adding properties for entity: com.aegis.kyc.entity.Address
2023-09-14T10:34:22.278-04:00  INFO 8084 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.c.i.m.AuditMetadataGenerator       : Adding properties for entity: com.aegis.kyc.entity.Document
2023-09-14T10:34:22.278-04:00  INFO 8084 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.c.i.m.AuditMetadataGenerator       : Adding properties for entity: com.aegis.kyc.entity.UserAccount
2023-09-14T10:34:22.278-04:00  INFO 8084 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.c.i.m.AuditMetadataGenerator       : Adding properties for entity: com.aegis.kyc.entity.Form
2023-09-14T10:34:22.279-04:00  INFO 8084 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.c.i.m.AuditMetadataGenerator       : Adding properties for entity: com.aegis.kyc.entity.OpportunityLineItem
2023-09-14T10:34:22.279-04:00  INFO 8084 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.c.i.m.AuditMetadataGenerator       : Adding properties for entity: com.aegis.kyc.entity.PoliticallyExposed
2023-09-14T10:34:22.279-04:00  INFO 8084 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.c.i.m.AuditMetadataGenerator       : Adding properties for entity: com.aegis.kyc.entity.FormSubSection
2023-09-14T10:34:22.283-04:00  INFO 8084 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.c.i.m.AuditMetadataGenerator       : Adding properties for entity: com.aegis.kyc.entity.FormPerson
2023-09-14T10:34:22.283-04:00  INFO 8084 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.c.i.m.AuditMetadataGenerator       : Adding properties for entity: com.aegis.kyc.entity.Plus10PercentShareholder
2023-09-14T10:34:22.283-04:00  INFO 8084 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.c.i.m.AuditMetadataGenerator       : Adding properties for entity: com.aegis.kyc.entity.Director
2023-09-14T10:34:22.284-04:00  INFO 8084 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.c.i.m.AuditMetadataGenerator       : Adding properties for entity: com.aegis.kyc.entity.AuthorizedSignatory
2023-09-14T10:34:22.284-04:00  INFO 8084 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.c.i.m.AuditMetadataGenerator       : Adding properties for entity: com.aegis.kyc.entity.KYCForm
2023-09-14T10:34:22.284-04:00  INFO 8084 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.c.i.m.AuditMetadataGenerator       : Adding properties for entity: com.aegis.kyc.entity.Person
2023-09-14T10:34:22.284-04:00  INFO 8084 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.c.i.m.AuditMetadataGenerator       : Adding properties for entity: com.aegis.kyc.entity.Employee
2023-09-14T10:34:22.284-04:00  INFO 8084 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.c.i.m.AuditMetadataGenerator       : Adding properties for entity: com.aegis.kyc.entity.ClientRep
2023-09-14T10:34:22.284-04:00  INFO 8084 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.c.i.m.AuditMetadataGenerator       : Adding properties for entity: com.aegis.kyc.entity.TouchPoint
2023-09-14T10:34:22.284-04:00  INFO 8084 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.c.i.m.AuditMetadataGenerator       : Adding properties for entity: com.aegis.kyc.entity.KeyFunctionaries
2023-09-14T10:34:22.284-04:00  INFO 8084 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.c.i.m.AuditMetadataGenerator       : Adding properties for entity: com.aegis.kyc.entity.Department
2023-09-14T10:34:22.285-04:00  INFO 8084 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.c.i.m.AuditMetadataGenerator       : Adding properties for entity: com.aegis.kyc.entity.OpportunityComment
2023-09-14T10:34:22.285-04:00  INFO 8084 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.c.i.m.AuditMetadataGenerator       : Adding properties for entity: com.aegis.kyc.entity.Company
2023-09-14T10:34:22.285-04:00  INFO 8084 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.c.i.m.AuditMetadataGenerator       : Adding properties for entity: com.aegis.kyc.entity.Message
2023-09-14T10:34:22.285-04:00  INFO 8084 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.c.i.m.AuditMetadataGenerator       : Adding properties for entity: com.aegis.kyc.entity.AffiliateRep
2023-09-14T10:34:22.397-04:00  INFO 8084 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.b.i.BytecodeProviderInitiator        : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : bytebuddy
2023-09-14T10:52:22.901-04:00  WARN 8084 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Java heap space
2023-09-14T10:52:22.904-04:00  INFO 8084 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2023-09-14T10:52:22.909-04:00  INFO 8084 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2023-09-14T10:52:22.912-04:00  INFO 8084 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2023-09-14T10:52:22.930-04:00  INFO 8084 --- [  restartedMain] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-09-14T10:52:22.955-04:00 ERROR 8084 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Java heap space
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1770) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1155) ~[spring-context-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932) ~[spring-context-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:608) ~[spring-context-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:436) ~[spring-boot-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312) ~[spring-boot-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at com.aegis.kyc.KycApplication.main(KycApplication.java:34) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:50) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.base/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.allocateInstance(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.invoke.DirectMethodHandle.allocateInstance(DirectMethodHandle.java:501) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.invoke.DirectMethodHandle$Holder.newInvokeSpecial(DirectMethodHandle$Holder) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.invoke.Invokers$Holder.linkToTargetMethod(Invokers$Holder) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.sql.ast.tree.expression.ColumnReference.appendReadExpression(ColumnReference.java:196) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.7.Final.jar:6.2.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.ast.tree.expression.ColumnReference.appendReadExpression(ColumnReference.java:171) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.7.Final.jar:6.2.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.ast.spi.AbstractSqlAstTranslator.visitColumnReference(AbstractSqlAstTranslator.java:6086) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.7.Final.jar:6.2.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.ast.tree.expression.ColumnReference.accept(ColumnReference.java:222) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.7.Final.jar:6.2.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.ast.spi.AbstractSqlAstTranslator.renderExpressionAsClauseItem(AbstractSqlAstTranslator.java:5035) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.7.Final.jar:6.2.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.ast.spi.AbstractSqlAstTranslator.renderSelectExpression(AbstractSqlAstTranslator.java:5020) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.7.Final.jar:6.2.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.ast.spi.AbstractSqlAstTranslator.visitSqlSelectExpression(AbstractSqlAstTranslator.java:5015) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.7.Final.jar:6.2.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.ast.spi.AbstractSqlAstTranslator.visitSqlSelection(AbstractSqlAstTranslator.java:4997) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.7.Final.jar:6.2.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.ast.spi.AbstractSqlAstTranslator.visitSqlSelections(AbstractSqlAstTranslator.java:4662) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.7.Final.jar:6.2.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerSqlAstTranslator.visitSqlSelections(SQLServerSqlAstTranslator.java:311) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.7.Final.jar:6.2.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.ast.spi.AbstractSqlAstTranslator.visitSelectClause(AbstractSqlAstTranslator.java:4563) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.7.Final.jar:6.2.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerSqlAstTranslator.visitSelectClause(SQLServerSqlAstTranslator.java:287) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.7.Final.jar:6.2.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.ast.spi.AbstractSqlAstTranslator.visitQuerySpec(AbstractSqlAstTranslator.java:3031) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.7.Final.jar:6.2.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerSqlAstTranslator.visitQuerySpec(SQLServerSqlAstTranslator.java:277) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.7.Final.jar:6.2.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.ast.tree.select.QuerySpec.accept(QuerySpec.java:119) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.7.Final.jar:6.2.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.ast.spi.AbstractSqlAstTranslator.visitSelectStatement(AbstractSqlAstTranslator.java:986) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.7.Final.jar:6.2.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.ast.spi.AbstractSqlAstTranslator.translateSelect(AbstractSqlAstTranslator.java:849) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.7.Final.jar:6.2.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.ast.spi.AbstractSqlAstTranslator.translate(AbstractSqlAstTranslator.java:799) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.7.Final.jar:6.2.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.SingleIdLoadPlan.<init>(SingleIdLoadPlan.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.7.Final.jar:6.2.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.SingleIdEntityLoaderStandardImpl.createLoadPlan(SingleIdEntityLoaderStandardImpl.java:197) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.7.Final.jar:6.2.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.SingleIdEntityLoaderStandardImpl.prepare(SingleIdEntityLoaderStandardImpl.java:55) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.7.Final.jar:6.2.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.prepareLoader(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3447) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.7.Final.jar:6.2.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.postInstantiate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3441) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.7.Final.jar:6.2.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.MappingMetamodelImpl.finishInitialization(MappingMetamodelImpl.java:204) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.7.Final.jar:6.2.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.initializeMappingModel(SessionFactoryImpl.java:320) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.7.Final.jar:6.2.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:270) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.7.Final.jar:6.2.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:431) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.7.Final.jar:6.2.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1455) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.7.Final.jar:6.2.7.Final]


Process finished with exit code 0
```

This is the where the console it stuck until the exception:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.1.2)

2023-09-19T11:55:56.710-04:00  INFO 800 --- [  restartedMain] com.aegis.kyc.KycApplication             : Starting KycApplication using Java 20.0.2 with PID 800 (C:\Users\Devopscrm\Desktop\New folder\kyc\target\classes started by DevopsCRM in C:\Users\Devopscrm\Desktop\New folder\kyc)
2023-09-19T11:55:56.711-04:00  INFO 800 --- [  restartedMain] com.aegis.kyc.KycApplication             : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-09-19T11:55:56.752-04:00  INFO 800 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2023-09-19T11:55:56.753-04:00  INFO 800 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2023-09-19T11:55:57.263-04:00  INFO 800 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-09-19T11:55:57.357-04:00  INFO 800 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 90 ms. Found 35 JPA repository interfaces.
2023-09-19T11:55:57.828-04:00  INFO 800 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8443 (https) 8080 (http)
2023-09-19T11:55:57.836-04:00  INFO 800 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-09-19T11:55:57.836-04:00  INFO 800 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.11]
2023-09-19T11:55:57.876-04:00  INFO 800 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-09-19T11:55:57.878-04:00  INFO 800 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1123 ms
2023-09-19T11:55:57.991-04:00  INFO 800 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2023-09-19T11:55:58.039-04:00  INFO 800 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.2.6.Final
2023-09-19T11:55:58.040-04:00  INFO 800 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000406: Using bytecode reflection optimizer
2023-09-19T11:55:58.122-04:00  INFO 800 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.boot.internal.EnversServiceImpl    : Envers integration enabled? : true
2023-09-19T11:55:58.137-04:00  INFO 800 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.b.i.BytecodeProviderInitiator        : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : bytebuddy
2023-09-19T11:55:58.218-04:00  INFO 800 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.o.j.p.SpringPersistenceUnitInfo      : No LoadTimeWeaver setup: ignoring JPA class transformer
2023-09-19T11:55:58.229-04:00  INFO 800 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2023-09-19T11:55:58.447-04:00  INFO 800 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection ConnectionID:1 ClientConnectionId: 3177f003-7ce9-4e36-b2a7-1f8e5044a8f5
2023-09-19T11:55:58.448-04:00  INFO 800 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2023-09-19T11:55:58.831-04:00  INFO 800 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.b.i.BytecodeProviderInitiator        : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : bytebuddy
```

Previously I added this to the `application.properties` file and the application did run, but it was on Spring `3.0.2` I was asked to try using `3.1.2` got the exception again:
`spring.datasource.hikari.minimum-idle=2`

This is the `pom.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.group</groupId>
    <artifactId>kyc</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>kyc</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <description>TouchPoint Application</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring.boot.version>3.1.2</spring.boot.version>
<!--        <hibernate.validator.version>your_version_here</hibernate.validator.version>-->
        <hibernate.version>6.1.6.Final</hibernate.version>
        <guava.version>32.1.2-jre</guava.version>
    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring Boot Starter Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>${hibernate.validator.version}</version>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.6.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>32.1.2-jre</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity6</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.10.1</version>
            <type>maven-plugin</type>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.awaitility</groupId>
            <artifactId>awaitility</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>17</source>
                    <target>17</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: The versions you mentioned don't match up with what is in your pom. Please double-check!

Comment: @Sören it should be fixed

Comment: Nope. The versions you mention in the post are still ancient. Did you mix a Spring and Spring Boot?

Comment: Why on earth is spring boot your parent project, and not a dependency?

Comment: @Rogue that's how it generated on https://start.spring.io/;

Comment: @Rogue Also, understand that I'm not the original author.

Comment: I have tried updating the `pom.xml` and fixing the version mismatches, please check it out.